# Google Content API - new version

Tags: .net, google-content-api

If I understand the latest updates from Google, they will discontinue the support for Global Endpoints for Google Content API.

When I look at their documentation I find this for .NET:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.ShoppingContent.v2_1/

Does anyone know if this is using the new endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default endpoint](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/39341689678e6e9a1826bc4c324122fbb58e225c/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.ShoppingContent.v2_1/Google.Apis.ShoppingContent.v2_1.cs#L102) is still https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2.1/, because that's what's currently in the [Discovery Doc](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/content/v2.1/rest). Once the Discovery document has been updated, the next release (which is automated) will reflect the change.

If you need to use the current client library version but want to explicitly specify the base URI yourself, you can do so using [BaseClientService.Initializer.BaseUri](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis/1.40.3/api/Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer.html#Google_Apis_Services_BaseClientService_Initializer_BaseUri).

Answer (score 1):

Its just that I got an email from Google Developers saying:

"Discontinuing support for JSON-RPC and Global HTTP Batch Endpoints"
and letting me know that i am using exactly what will be discontinued in my "Content API for Shopping"